# Choosing direction in DFS maze generation

Tags: depth-first-search, maze

I've recently implemented a DFS maze generation algorithm according to the standard procedure:

- Fill a maze with walls
- Choose a starting square
- Choose a random neighbor and break the wall between that neighbor if that neighbor hasn't already been explored
- Recursively generate the rest of the maze by starting at the neighbor

I've been told that I may be able to "aesthetically" improve the generated mazes by implementing a rule for choosing which neighbor to explore (north, south, east or west) that isn't just completely random, but I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what kind of rule that would be. Are there any methods out there that involve choosing a direction non-randomly, or randomly with weights? I haven't been able to find any so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many indeed.

DFS is uninformed search, so I would recommend having a look at **informed search** and how they are applicable to mazes.